# Why does ‘freedom’ return the french fries  emoji?

Tags: macos, text-input, emoji

In my emoji picker when I enter `freedom` I see some french fries.

[image: macOS character/emoji picker showing search for ‘freedom’ returning french fries emoji]

Why is that?

#### Practical example:

So if I want to write something like the following:

> People of the world appreciate what you're given, go out there and enjoy your **freedom**

So emojifying the above quote is somewhat dangerous:

> of the , appreciate what you're given, go out there and enjoy your .

Comment: I'd say that emojifying *any* proper text is somewhat dangerous

Comment: This makes me feel old...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The  emoji is offered as an option for any search matching the string **‘[freedom fries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_fries)’**, which

> was a political euphemism for French fries in the United States. The term was born in 2003 when the then Republican Chairman of the Committee on House Administration, Bob Ney, renamed the menu item in three Congressional cafeterias in response to France's opposition to the proposed invasion of Iraq.

In the character picker, any prefix substring match on a word relating to that emoji will present the emoji for selection. Therefore ‘free’ or ‘freedom’ will match ‘freedom fries’.

[image]

#### Where does the OS find these strings?

**<sub>[image]</sub> CoreEmoji.framework** contains a list of emojis and relevant search strings, per locale, in

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/Versions/A/Resources/en.lproj/
```

replacing `en` with the locale. For the strings used by the character picker when searching, look in **CharacterPicker.strings**. For example:

```
/System/L*/Priv*/CoreE*/V*/A/R*/en.*/C*
```

Open the <sub>[image]</sub>.strings file as a <sub>[image]</sub>.plist in Xcode to prettyprint it as shown above, or use `plutil`:

```xml
$ plutil -extract "" xml1 -o - /System/L*/Priv*/CoreE*/V*/A/R*/en.*/C*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>fries | freedom fries | french fries | fast food | junk food | food | object</string>
</plist>
```

```
$ plutil -convert json -o - /System/L*/Priv*/CoreE*/V*/A/R*/en.*/C* | jq -r ".[\"\"]"
fries | freedom fries | french fries | fast food | junk food | food | object
```

#### I don't want QuickType to suggest  as an autocomplete to ‘freedom’!

**It won't.** QuickType autocomplete emoji suggestions, or Messages tap-to-replace words with emojis when the emoji keyboard is shown, is defined by another file, **FindReplace.strings**.

Emojis are suggested as word replacements when an entire word in the original text matches an entire word in a string relating to the emoji. The word ‘freedom’ will not be replaced by the emoji since the ‘freedom fries’ phrase only exists in CharacterPicker.strings, not FindReplace.strings.

```
$ plutil -convert json -o - /System/L*/Priv*/CoreE*/V*/A/R*/en.*/F* | jq -r ".[\"\"]"
fries | french fries | french fry
```

[image: ‘fries’ showing fries emoji]
[image: ‘freedom’ not showing fries emoji]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85245/discussion-on-answer-by-grg-what-has-french-fries-to-do-with-freedom-emoji-wise).

Comment: Was this a Unicode standard that was embedded in iOS or was it something Apple added to the Unicode so that emoji were searchable (or even a crowd sourced database Apple allowed to give names to things?)

Answer (score 9):

## It doesn't (any more)

As of MacOS 10.14.4 (released Mar 25, 2019), "freedom fries" is no longer a search keyword for the  french fries emoji.

[image]

I checked before and after upgrading from MacOS 10.14.1 (released Oct 30, 2018)  to confirm that this was a recent change.

[image]

---

The removal was plausibly a result of this Stack Exchange thread (posted Nov 2, 2018). I can't find anybody else on the internet drawing attention to this keyword until this question was posted. This question got over nine thousand views and was a Stack Exchange "Hot Network Question", and then I emailed Tim Cook for good measure.

> #### “Freedom Fries” used in Apple’s emoji picker
>
> *Date: Fri, 2 Nov 2018 12:39:08 -0400*
>   *To: Tim Cook <tcook@apple.com>*
>   *From: Jeremy Banks*
>
> Hello Tim,
>
> I just wanted to draw your attention to the fact that the phrase “freedom fries”, a potentially offensive and dated political meme, is one of the search terms used by Apple’s emoji picker. (It’s listed in the CharacterPicker.plist file.)
>
> Please consider removing this keyword.
>
> Thank you.
>
> - An Apple User