# Decoding DAT files in System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework on Big Sur

Tags: emoji, big-sur

On previous macOS such as Mojave and Catalina, the mappings between emoji unicodes and associated keywords were available to view in files like `CharacterPicker` and `FindReplace` in `.plists` or `.strings` data formats [1]. These files were found in `System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/Versions/A/Resources`.

On Big Sur, it seems that only the `.dat` formats of those files are shipped. It is possible to decode these files back into a `.plists` or `.strings` format?

[1] [Why does ‘freedom’ return the french fries 🍟 emoji?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341459/why-does-freedom-return-the-french-fries-emoji)

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?

Comment: @Jeef nope :'( But tell me if you do.

Comment: I'm on an older OS, but what happens if you copy the `.dat` file to a user-writable location (e.g. your desktop) and run `plutil -convert xml1 /path/to/file.dath`? Failing that, what is the output of `file /path/to/file.dat`?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy plutil result: `CharacterPicker-en.dat: Property List error: Unexpected character Ñ at line 1 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.` file result: `CharacterPicker-en.dat: data`

Comment: It happens that the DAT file consists of (at least) two parts. The first part is a Marisa Trie (starting from "We love Marisa".) It is a set of string keys. The 4 bytes right before the trie is its length. I haven't figured out the second part yet.

Comment: This might help in parsing and analyzing `.dat` files, which could be a first step in decoding them into formats like `.plists` or `.strings`.

[Analyzing .dat Files Script](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/7fb4ee9d84cd41c7a745de5949ed4c1b)

This script aims to identify repeating patterns in binary files, which could be crucial for understanding the data structure of the `.dat` files.